# Sound level initially goes to 100% when adjusting

Tags: arch-linux, kde, pulseaudio

I've got a DAC connected through USB-C with a weird quirk: after booting, when I adjust the volume, it will first go to 100% volume - nearly blowing out my speakers - before setting the correct level.

I've read multiple tips on setting the correct volume at boot. But that isn't a problem: I specified in `default.pa` (PulseAudio) the default device and volume. It's set to 20% and that's exactly what it is upon boot. Very nice!

However, when I want to increase the volume, it first goes to 100% and then to 25%. So this puzzles me, because it sets it properly on boot and also picks up at the right point after going to 100%. Does this sound familiar to anyone? And how can I solve it?

Comment: What are you using to change the volume? Is it a GUI item in the kde desktop? You might try launching the `pavucontrol` GUI to see if it has the same problem. If so try `pactl set-sink-volume ...` to set the volume again after boot and then try the GUI. I don't know where to look for the bug, I'm just trying to find a way round it.

Comment: @meuh thanks for your suggestion, much appreciated! Yes, I'm using a shortkey to adjust volume. I tried out your suggestion, the result was interesting: when launching `pavucontrol` and then adjusting the volume, the slider would move very slowly, ie. my mouse cursor was way ahead of where the slider was. Then the sound would 'pop' to 100% and when I continue sliding, the slider snaps to my mouse cursor. So it's almost like the scaling is off initially and then it corrects itself. I will try to see if there's any more info about this 'scaling' behavior.

Comment: There are several hacks for pulseaudio in archlinux including [this
one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Pops_when_starting_and_stopping_playback),
about disabling module-suspend-on-idle. It even references KDE and slider volume.